# How can I share a scrollstate between a Column and a LazyVerticalGrid?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following layout that uses Jetpack Compose. It is fairly complicated and uses a scrollstate that is shared between multiple views to facilitate the animation. This works perfectly if using a normal column. However, when I try to use a LazyVerticalGrid, I get this error.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed.

I can make it run by setting the LazyVerticalGrid's height to 1000 so that it isn't infinite, but it results in 2 scrollables. One is the header and toolbar area, and the other is the LazyVerticalGrid. Is there any way to do this that shares the scrollstate between all of the composables? I understand that you can't have infinite maximum height constraints, but there must be something that can be done here........

See Animation here https://imgur.com/a/62FgaDl

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.animation.fadeIn
import androidx.compose.animation.fadeOut
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.statusBarsPadding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridItemSpan
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyVerticalGrid
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.MoreVert
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.State
import androidx.compose.runtime.derivedStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.BlurEffect
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.TileMode
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.graphicsLayer
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.onGloballyPositioned
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.SpanStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.buildAnnotatedString
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
import androidx.compose.ui.text.withStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.lerp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.compose.ui.zIndex
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import com.example.twittercollapsingtoolbar.ui.theme.BrownTransparent
import com.example.twittercollapsingtoolbar.ui.theme.Gray
import com.example.twittercollapsingtoolbar.ui.theme.TwitterCollapsingToolbarTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TwitterCollapsingToolbarTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    TwitterCollapsingToolbar()
                }
            }
        }
        actionBar?.hide()
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    }
}

val headerHeight = 140.dp
val toolbarHeight = 56.dp
val collapseRange = headerHeight - toolbarHeight
val avatarSize = 90.dp
val paddingMedium = 16.dp
val paddingSmall = 4.dp

@Composable
fun TwitterCollapsingToolbar() {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val titleHeight = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val collapseRangePx = with(LocalDensity.current) { collapseRange.toPx() }
    val avatarSizePx = with(LocalDensity.current) { avatarSize.toPx() }
    val profileNameTopPaddingPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { paddingSmall.toPx() }
    val paddingMediumPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { paddingMedium.toPx() }

    val collapseRangeReached = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            scrollState.value >= (collapseRangePx)
        }
    }

    val avatarZIndex = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (collapseRangeReached.value)
                0f
            else
                2f
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
    ) { padding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .zIndex(0f)
                    .background(Color.Black)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
            ) {
                Spacer(Modifier.height(headerHeight))
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.edit_profile),
                    color = Gray,
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.End)
                        .padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
                        .border(1.dp, Gray, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
                )

                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier.height(1000.dp)
                ) {

                    item(span = {
                        GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
                    }) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Title",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(top = paddingSmall, start = paddingMedium)
                                .onGloballyPositioned {
                                    titleHeight.value = it.size.height.toFloat()
                                }
                        )
                    }

                    item(span = {
                        GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
                    }) {
                        Text("Items")
                    }

                    items(20) { index ->
                        ItemListItem()
                    }
                }
            }

            Header(scrollState, collapseRangePx, Modifier.zIndex(1f), collapseRangeReached)
            Avatar(
                scrollState,
                collapseRangePx,
                paddingMediumPx,
                collapseRangeReached,
                avatarZIndex
            )
            Toolbar(
                scrollState,
                collapseRangePx,
                titleHeight,
                avatarSizePx,
                profileNameTopPaddingPx,
                collapseRangeReached,
                Modifier
                    .zIndex(3f)
                    .statusBarsPadding()
            )
            ToolbarActions(
                Modifier
                    .zIndex(4f)
                    .statusBarsPadding()
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemListItem() {
    Card() {
        Column {
            val imageModifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 0.dp, bottomStart = 12.dp, bottomEnd = 12.dp))
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                contentDescription = "Title",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier = imageModifier
            )
            Text(
                "Title",
                maxLines = 2,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Header(
    scrollState: ScrollState, collapseRangePx: Float, modifier: Modifier,
    showToolbar: State<Boolean>
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !showToolbar.value,
        enter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(600)),
        exit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(600)),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(headerHeight)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    val collapseFraction = (scrollState.value / collapseRangePx).coerceIn(0f, 1f)
                    val yTranslation = lerp(
                        0.dp,
                        -(headerHeight - toolbarHeight),
                        collapseFraction
                    )
                    translationY = yTranslation.toPx()

                    val blur = lerp(0.dp, 3.dp, collapseFraction)
                    if (blur != 0.dp) {
                        renderEffect = BlurEffect(blur.toPx(), blur.toPx(), TileMode.Decal)
                    }
                }
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                contentDescription = "",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Avatar(
    scrollState: ScrollState,
    collapseRangePx: Float,
    paddingPx: Float,
    switch: State<Boolean>,
    avatarZIndex: State<Float>
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .zIndex(avatarZIndex.value)
            .graphicsLayer {
                val collapseFraction = (scrollState.value / collapseRangePx).coerceIn(0f, 1f)

                val scaleXY = lerp(
                    1.dp,
                    0.5.dp,
                    collapseFraction
                )

                val yTranslation = lerp(
                    headerHeight - (avatarSize / 2),
                    toolbarHeight - (avatarSize * ((1.dp - scaleXY) / 2.dp)),
                    collapseFraction
                )

                translationY = if (switch.value)
                    (toolbarHeight.toPx() - (avatarSize.toPx() * ((1.dp - scaleXY) / 2.dp)) -
                            (scrollState.value - collapseRange.toPx()))
                else
                    yTranslation.toPx()

                translationX = paddingPx

                scaleX = scaleXY.value
                scaleY = scaleXY.value
            }

    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(avatarSize)
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .border(paddingSmall, Color.Black, CircleShape)
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun Toolbar(
    scrollState: ScrollState,
    collapseRangePx: Float,
    titleHeight: MutableState<Float>,
    avatarSizePx: Float,
    profileNameTopPaddingPx: Float,
    showToolbar: State<Boolean>,
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    val showTitle by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            scrollState.value >=
                    collapseRangePx + avatarSizePx / 2 + profileNameTopPaddingPx + titleHeight.value
        }
    }

    val title = buildAnnotatedString {
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.W700)) {
            append(stringResource(id = R.string.profile_name))
        }
        append("\n")
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontSize = 16.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.W400)) {
            append(stringResource(id = R.string.tweets))
        }
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = showToolbar.value,
        enter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(600)),
        exit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(600)),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        TopAppBar(
            navigationIcon = {},
            title = {
                if (showTitle) {
                    Text(text = title)
                }
            },
            elevation = 0.dp
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun ToolbarActions(modifier: Modifier) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(toolbarHeight)
    ) {
        IconAction(
            Modifier.padding(top = paddingMedium, start = paddingMedium),
            Icons.Default.ArrowBack
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        IconAction(
            Modifier.padding(top = paddingMedium, end = paddingMedium),
            Icons.Default.MoreVert
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun IconAction(modifier: Modifier, image: ImageVector) {
    IconButton(
        onClick = {},
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .size(32.dp)
            .background(BrownTransparent)
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = image,
            contentDescription = "",
            tint = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingSmall)
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    TwitterCollapsingToolbarTheme {
        TwitterCollapsingToolbar()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1-) You can't measure a Composable with Constraints.Infinity, which comes from vertical scroll to child, but it doesn't mean you have to set a fixed heigt. You can use Modifier.heighIn(max=1000.dp) which means your Composable is measured between 0-1000.dp. If its content's total height is less than 1000.dp, for instance 400.dp, it gets height of the content. This is optional you can set fixed height or use maxiumum non-infinite bounds.

2-) You can just set `userScrollEnabled = false` on LazyVerticalGrid to move it based on Column scroll but this alone will not scroll grid when Column reaches end.

You can create a NestedScrollConnection and set scroll of grid using preScroll function. You can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77048937/android-how-to-listen-to-scroll-in-a-column-modifier-verticalscroll/77048996#77048996) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76930102/how-can-i-scroll-a-custom-layout-and-lazycolumn-in-the-same-row-as-if-they-are-o/76931668#76931668).

```
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            val delta = -available.y
            coroutineScope.launch {
                lazyGridState.scrollBy(delta)
            }
            return Offset.Zero
        }

    }
}
```

And using it

```
Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .zIndex(0f)
        .background(Color.Black)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    Spacer(Modifier.height(headerHeight))
    Text(
        text = "Edit Profile",
        color = Gray,
        fontSize = 14.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.End)
            .padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
            .border(1.dp, Gray, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
    )

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        state = lazyGridState,
        userScrollEnabled = false,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
//                    modifier = Modifier.height( 1000.dp)
        modifier = Modifier.heightIn(max = 1000.dp)
    ) {
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/scroll#parent-compose-child-view

You can also do it without setting userScrollEnabled to false by scrolling Column when a LazyGrid is scrolled with

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {

            val delta = -available.y
            coroutineScope.launch {
                if (scrollState.isScrollInProgress.not()) {
                    scrollState.scrollBy(delta)
                }
            }
            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

## Optimization Edit

And to optimize this further remove verticalScroll from Column and set LazyVerticalGrid height to screen height and add Text with edit profile as item of LazyGrid. Doing this will only recompose 6 items and will have better scroll experience than scrolling vertical scroll or LazyVerticalGrid.

By the way if implementation didn't rely on scrollState it could also be removed and values can be set inside onPreScroll function but in current implementation Header, Toolbar, ToolbarActions rely on vertical scroll state.

```
@Composable
fun TwitterCollapsingToolbar() {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val titleHeight = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val collapseRangePx = with(LocalDensity.current) { collapseRange.toPx() }
    val avatarSizePx = with(LocalDensity.current) { avatarSize.toPx() }
    val profileNameTopPaddingPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { paddingSmall.toPx() }
    val paddingMediumPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { paddingMedium.toPx() }

    val screenWidthDp = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp
    val screenHeightDp = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp

    val lazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState()


    val collapseRangeReached = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            scrollState.value >= (collapseRangePx)
        }
    }

    val avatarZIndex = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (collapseRangeReached.value)
                0f
            else
                2f
        }
    }

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {

                val delta = -available.y
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    if (scrollState.isScrollInProgress.not()) {
                        scrollState.scrollBy(delta)
                    }
                }
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
    ) { padding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()

        ) {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .zIndex(0f)
                    .background(Color.Black)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
            ) {

                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                    state = lazyGridState,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier.height(screenHeightDp)
                ) {

                    item(
                        span = {
                            GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
                        }
                    ) {
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                // This layout is to match size to parent because
                                // inside LazyVerticalGrid we are constraint with horizontal
                                // padding
                                .layout { measurable: Measurable, constraints: Constraints ->
                                    val placeable = measurable.measure(
                                        constraints.copy(
                                            minWidth = screenWidthDp.roundToPx(),
                                            maxWidth = screenWidthDp.roundToPx()
                                        )
                                    )
                                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                                        placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                                    }
                                }
                        ) {
                            Spacer(Modifier.height(headerHeight - 16.dp))
                            Text(
                                text = "Edit Profile",
                                color = Color.Gray,
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .align(Alignment.End)
                                    .padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
                                    .border(1.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
                                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    item(span = {
                        GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
                    }) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Title",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(top = paddingSmall, start = paddingMedium)
                                .onGloballyPositioned {
                                    titleHeight.value = it.size.height.toFloat()
                                }
                        )
                    }

                    item(span = {
                        GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
                    }) {
                        Text("Items")
                    }

                    items(20) { index ->
                        ItemListItem()
                    }
                }
            }

            Header(scrollState, collapseRangePx, Modifier.zIndex(1f), collapseRangeReached)
            Avatar(
                scrollState,
                collapseRangePx,
                paddingMediumPx,
                collapseRangeReached,
                avatarZIndex
            )
            Toolbar(
                scrollState,
                collapseRangePx,
                titleHeight,
                avatarSizePx,
                profileNameTopPaddingPx,
                collapseRangeReached,
                Modifier
                    .zIndex(3f)
                    .statusBarsPadding()
            )
            ToolbarActions(
                Modifier
                    .zIndex(4f)
                    .statusBarsPadding()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it make lazyGrid items to be calculated at once? which means will it lose the "lazy" property or continue to draw as items scroll in?

Comment: It won't lose lazy property because lazy means "The vertically scrolling list that only composes and lays out the currently visible items.". When you set height to 1000.dp or maxHeight to 1000.dp where you set viewPort height which makes every item visible in your LazyList because of that they all be recomposed initially. But if there are items after 1000.dp they will be recomposed while you scroll up or down. It's a design choice how tall you wish to set a LazyList. You can do it without nested scroll with 40.dp or 200.dp and it determines how many items to be composed

Comment: You can think of this when you set a LazyColumn fillmaxSize and it has items with total height less than LazyColumn, does it lose lazy propery. It doesn't as you add new items while sum of height of items less than Viewport height they get composed but after Viewport height is reached, or sum is bigger than height of LazyColumn rest is composed after you scroll

Comment: It depends. In first and second samples LazyGrid with 1000.dp, it's total height, composes all of the items in 1000.dp on my device it's 12 items and as you scroll items are recomposed when they enter Viewport of LazyVerticalGrid. In third one i put edit into LazyVerticalGrid and set its total height to parent height and it only recomposes 6 items initially and as other get visible on screen all items get recomposed.

Comment: Also in first and second example if you assign Modifier.heightIn(max=2000.dp) to LazyVerticalGrid it can be measured with its content height, let's say 1500.dp, every items gets composed initially as you have a vertical scrollable Column but whenever you scroll up or down grid items are never recomposed. If they are some Video or slow to initialize i would have used first or second or set total height big so they don't have to be recomposed on scroll over and over again.

Comment: This is matter of design how big your LazyColumn/Grid you want it be. In a plain example if you have 200.dp height LazyColumn with 100.dp items only 3 items get composed at any moment, if you set height 600.dp 4 items and so on. When you set full screen LazyList you are recomposing number of items that are visible at any moment and one on scroll direction before it enters Viewport

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It is so close to what I am looking for. However, it has a flaw. The scrollstate does not update once it's value exceeds(in my case) 726. This causes it to think it has reached the collapse range before it should. It is easy to reproduce this by adding 50 items to the grid and scrolling to the bottom then scrolling back up. Here is a screen recording of the issue. https://imgur.com/a/VPkYKET. I am wondering if your comment about removing scrollstate would help with this, but I don't understand what would replace it. Thank you!

Comment: @CameronHenige have you tried the last sample. I had no issue with that one. In other 2 sample you need to set heightIn(max=2000.dp) to have vertical grid measured with full height. That's what we discussed initially. My initial answer had 2000.dp range to measure grid with it's total height. It's an arbitrary number to let it to be measured in a range 0-some arbitrary number in dp instead of Infinite number Constraints.Infinity is not allowed.

Comment: Measurement in Jetpack Compose is done using Constraints min and max values so instead of infinite constraints that passed to content when you use Modifier.vertical scroll which is not allowed for inner scroll or LazyLists i proposed to use non infinite number to have full height LazyVerticalGrid inside Column

Comment: Also, added each example here https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter5_gesture/Tutorial5_9_7CollapsingTopAppbar2.kt