# How to have a LazyColumn inside a Column and scroll it as a one?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following composable tree:

```
Column {
  SomeComposable()

  SomeComposable2()

  HorizontalPager {
     LazyColumn() // Tab 1
     LazyColumn() // Tab 2
  }

}
```

This crashed because of nested scrollable containers. So I gave the Horizontal Pager a fixed height.

I has to use nested Column / LazyColumn, because Flattening the layout into single `LazyColumn` is not possible because of `HorizontalPager`.

```
Column {
  SomeComposable()

  SomeComposable2()

  Box(Modifier.height(SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
     HorizontalPager {
        LazyColumn() // Tab 1
        LazyColumn() // Tab 2
     }
  }
}
```

This doesn't crash, but now there are couple of problems:

1. The Inner lazycolumns scroll independently,  but the expectation is for the whole column to scroll as single column.
2. Since the horizontal pager has fixed height, if the list has fewer items, there would be blank space.

How to make this usecase work?

Comment: You can use NestedScrollConnection and you don't have to give fixed height. If you set Modifier.heighIn(max = the height you set for fixed height) you will be able to have a Composable that can have height between 0.dp and fixed height depending on total height of content

Comment: You can check out these answer for scrolling LazyColumns or other Scrollable items together. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76930102/how-can-i-scroll-a-custom-layout-and-lazycolumn-in-the-same-row-as-if-they-are-o/76931668#76931668, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77056791/5457853

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Thracian, earlier I tried to resolve the problem with NestedScrollConnection but the usage was bit off. Though I didn't use your solutions as is for my usecase helped get good understanding of NestedScrollConnection to fix for my usecase.